# How to fix Windows 10 VM not booting

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I... have a predicament.

Using VirtualBox, I downloaded a Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft, plugged it into a new VM, and fired it up. Everything worked fine until I needed to install the Guest Additions addon. I installed it, then restarted for it to show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xuu8.jpg). It happens every time I load it, and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: This won't help you but virtualbox was nothing but problems for me. This happened to me many many many times. I finally switched over to VMware. 10000% better. One of my virtual OS's has been functioning for 2 years now without a single issue.

Comment: Try enabling / disabling 2D/3D Acceleration in Virtualbox

Comment: @Klinghust Didn't work. I was already running both, so I tried just 3d, just 2d, and neither. No help.